# Powerbuilder multiple select in dropdown

Tags: dropdown, powerbuilder, multipleselection

Is there a multiple select option for the datawindow dropdown in powerbuilder? I have a dropdown (dddw) and I need to select more than one value. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  A dropdowndatawindow is a single select object.  You can do this via a listbox.  [Here is a link](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/480678?page=0,1) which may help you from the old PowerBuilder Developers Journal.  You basically set the muli select property of the listbox to true.  Populate the entries.  Then loop through the selected items.

There also is a [discussion string on this topic](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3802653) in the SAP archives (SAP used to own PowerBuilder).  There is a custom control by Balu Ramasamy which may help too.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how to make Powerbuilder select multiple rows in a dropdowndatawindow, but I had a situation where it did select multiple rows and I didn’t want it to.  I had to turn off the prior row and reselect the new row.  I added this code to the itemchanged event when transaction_reason changed.

```
DataWindowChild ldwc_Reason
this.GetChild('transaction_reason', ldwc_Reason)
// unselect prior reason's'
ldwc_Reason.selectrow( 0, false)
// select the current reason
ldwc_Reason.selectrow( ldwc_Reason.getrow(), true)
```